# jOOQ can I fetch a join of two tables into the respective POJOs

Tags: java, jooq

In jOOQ if I want to fetch a row of a table into a jOOQ autogenerated POJOs I do, for instance:

```
dsl.selectFrom(USER)
                .where(USER.U_EMAIL.equal(email))
                .fetchOptionalInto(User.class);
```

Now, suppose that I want to do a join between two tables, e.g. `USER` and `ROLE`, how can I fetch the result into the POJOs for these two tables?

Comment: How are user and role connected? One-to-many? Many-to-one? Many-to-many?

Comment: many-to-many, so yes, there is a table UserToRole also

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Using nested collections

With more recent versions of jOOQ, you'll typically use a set of ORDBMS features, including:

- [nested collections using `MULTISET`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/)
- [nested records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/) and [nested table records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/)
- [ad-hoc converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/)

You'll write something like this, to produce jOOQ types:

```java
Result<Record2<UserRecord, Result<Record1<RoleRecord>>>> result =
dsl.select(
        USER,
        multiset(
            selectFrom(USER_ROLE.role())
            .where(USER_ROLE.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))
        ))
   .from(USER)
   .where(USER.U_EMAIL.equal(email))
   .fetch();
```

Or, by using said [ad-hoc converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/), to produce your own types:

```java
List<User> result =
dsl.select(
        USER.U_ID,
        USER.U_EMAIL, 
        ...
        multiset(
            selectFrom(USER_ROLE.role())
            .where(USER_ROLE.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))
        ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Role::new))))
   .from(USER)
   .where(USER.U_EMAIL.equal(email))
   .fetch(Records.mapping(User::new));
```

### Historic answers / alternatives

There are other ways to achieve something like the above, for completeness' sake:

#### Fetching the POJOs into a `Map`

This is one solution using [`ResultQuery.fetchGroups(RecordMapper, RecordMapper)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchGroups-org.jooq.RecordMapper-org.jooq.RecordMapper-)

```java
Map<UserPojo, List<RolePojo>> result =
dsl.select(USER.fields())
   .select(ROLE.fields())
   .from(USER)
   .join(USER_TO_ROLE).on(USER.USER_ID.eq(USER_TO_ROLE.USER_ID))
   .join(ROLE).on(ROLE.ROLE_ID.eq(USER_TO_ROLE.ROLE_ID))
   .where(USER.U_EMAIL.equal(email))
   .fetchGroups(

       // Map records first into the USER table and then into the key POJO type
       r -> r.into(USER).into(UserPojo.class),

       // Map records first into the ROLE table and then into the value POJO type
       r -> r.into(ROLE).into(RolePojo.class)
   );
```

Note, if you want to use `LEFT JOIN` instead (in case a user does not necessarily have any roles, and you want to get an empty list per user), you'll have to translate `NULL` roles to empty lists yourself.

Make sure you have activated generating `equals()` and `hashCode()` on your POJOs in order to be able to put them in a `HashMap` as keys:

```xml
<pojosEqualsAndHashCode>true</pojosEqualsAndHashCode>
```

#### Using custom, hierarchical POJOs and fetching them into a nested collection

A frequently re-occurring question is how to fetch nested collections in jOOQ, i.e. what if your result data structures look like this:

```java
class User {
  long id;
  String email;
  List<Role> roles;
}

class Role {
  long id;
  String name;
}
```

Starting with jOOQ 3.14, and if your RDBMS supports it, you can now use SQL/XML or SQL/JSON as an intermediary format to nest collections, and then use Jackson, Gson, or JAXB to map the document back to your Java classes (or keep the XML or JSON, if that's what you needed in the first place). For example:

```java
List<User> users =
ctx.select(
      USER.ID,
      USER.EMAIL,
      field(
        select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(ROLE.ID, ROLE.NAME)))
        .from(ROLES)
        .join(USER_TO_ROLE).on(ROLE.ROLE_ID.eq(USER_TO_ROLE.ROLE_ID))
        .where(USER_TO_ROLE.USER.ID.eq(USER.ID))
      ).as("roles")
    )
    .from(USER)
    .where(USER.EMAIL.eq(email))
    .fetchInto(User.class);
```

Note that `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` aggregates empty sets into `NULL`, not into an empty `[]`. [If that's a problem, use `COALESCE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932476/521799)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But just wondered how this can be combined with `fetchLazy`?

Comment: @Kango_V: Good point. These two features currently cannot be combined. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6046. You can, of course, transform your `Cursor` (from `fetchLazy()`) into a Java 8 `Stream` and then use `collect()` to group results...

Comment: how does this work for a one to many relation ship? We have a Feature table and a Tier table, 1 tier can have multiple features. So wanted to query and get output as Map<Byte,List<String>> byte corresponds to a tierID and list of feature names.

Comment: @user160108 use [`fetchGroups(TIER_ID, FEATURE_NAME)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchGroups-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-)

Comment: @LukasEder that worked, had another query is it also possible to map to a pojo like Map<Byte,List<FeaturePojo>> for one to many relationship?

Comment: Figure it did this .intoGroups(FreemiumFeature.FREEMIUM_FEATURE.ID,c->c.into(FreemiumTierFeature.FREEMIUM_TIER_FEATURE).into(FeatureCondition.class));

Comment: The documentation of fetchGroup() doesn't say whether the returned map preserves ordering of the roles, so going to assume it doesn't. Would be useful to know if it does and should be in the docs if implemented.

Comment: But it *is* documented (soon: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11154) :)

Answer (score 3):

continuing good answer of Lukas Eder:

If you need list structure in return or you can not ovveride equals or hashcode in your POJO you can fetch it into List<Pair>

```
               List<Pair<UserPojo, RolePojo>> result = dsl.select(USER.fields())
               .select(ROLE.fields())
               .from(USER)
      .join(USER_TO_ROLE).on(USER.USER_ID.eq(USER_TO_ROLE.USER_ID))
      .join(ROLE).on(ROLE.ROLE_ID.eq(USER_TO_ROLE.ROLE_ID))
      .where(USER.U_EMAIL.equal(email))
       .fetch(record -> {
                UserPojo userPojo = r.into(USER).into(UserPojo.class);
                RolePojo rolePojo = r.into(ROLE).into(RolePojo.class);
                return new ImmutablePair<>(zoneEntity, userEntity);
            });
```