# Fetch into Map for a one to many relationship in JOOQ

Tags: jooq

We have a Feature table and a Tier table, 1 tier can have multiple features. So wanted to query and get output as

```
Map<Byte,List<String>>
```

byte corresponds to a tierID and list of feature names

Managed to get an answer from an older post here 
[Question](http://%3Chttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222957/jooq-can-i-fetch-a-join-of-two-tables-into-the-respective-pojos%3E)

Further we wanted to get a map of

```
Map<id, List<List<FeaturePojo>>
```

Comment: Note for others who might find this question, [starting from jOOQ 3.14, it's possible to nest collections when mapping results into POJOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64385482/521799)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working, using the following

```
.intoGroups(FreemiumFeature.FREEMIUM_FEATURE.ID,
            c->c.into(Fr‌​eemiumTierFeature.FR‌​EEMIUM_TIER_FEATURE)‌​
           .into(FeaturePojo.class));
```