# JOOQ fetch over foreign keys table

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have three tables:

```
Users
Keys
UserKeys
```

The `UserKeys` table has both primary keys from `Users` and `Keys` tables to establish the relation between users and keys.

How to fetch a `User` with all it's related keys?

What if additional tables exist (for instance `UserRoles`), etc. In general, how to fetch a user and all associated rows, related via foreign keys tables?

Comment: In Jooq or SQL?

Comment: @jarlh JOOQ is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using standard SQL `JOIN`

I'm assuming you're using jOOQ's [code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/). You write a join just like you would write a join in SQL:

```java
ctx.select() // Optionally, list columns here, explicitly
   .from(USERS)
   .join(USER_KEYS).on(USERS.ID.eq(USER_KEYS.USER_ID))
   .join(KEYS).on(USER_KEYS.KEY_ID.eq(KEYS.ID))
   .where(USERS.NAME.eq("something"))
   .fetch();
```

#### Nesting collections

> What if additional tables exist (for instance UserRoles), etc. In general, how to fetch a user and all associated rows, related via foreign keys tables?

I'm not sure if this is still the same question. The above may have been about how to do joins in general, this one seems to be more specific about how to fetch nested collections?

Because a `JOIN` will always produce cartesian products, which are undesirable, once you're joining several to-many paths. Starting from jOOQ 3.14, you can use SQL/XML or SQL/JSON as a workaround for this, if your database supports that. Starting from jOOQ 3.15, you can use `MULTISET`. For example, the JSON solution might look like this:

```java
List<User> users =
ctx.select(jsonObject(
     jsonEntry("id", USERS.ID),
     jsonEntry("name", USERS.NAME),
     jsonEntry("keys", field(
       select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(KEYS.NAME, KEYS.ID)))
       .from(KEYS)
       .join(USER_KEYS).on(KEYS.ID.eq(USER_KEYS.KEY_ID))
       .where(USER_KEYS.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))
     )),
     jsonEntry("roles", field(
       select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(ROLES.NAME, ROLES.ID)))
       .from(ROLES)
       .join(USER_ROLES).on(ROLES.ID.eq(USER_ROLES.ROLE_ID))
       .where(USER_ROLES.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))
     ))
   ))
   .from(USERS)
   .where(USERS.NAME.eq("something"))
   .fetchInto(User.class);
```

Assuming the `User` class looks like this, and that you have Gson or Jackson on your classpath to map from JSON to your Java data structures:

```java
class Key {
  long id;
  String name;
}

class Role {
  long id;
  String name;
}

class User {
  long id;
  String name;

  List<Key> keys;
  List<Role> roles;
}
```

Of course, you don't have to map to Java data structures and produce a JSON result directly, without further mapping. [See also this blog post for more details](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/10/09/nesting-collections-with-jooq-3-14s-sql-xml-or-sql-json-support/), or [this one explaining how to use `MULTISET`](https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/06/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/).

Note that `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` aggregates empty sets into `NULL`, not into an empty `[]`. [If that's a problem, use `COALESCE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932476/521799)

The `MULTISET` solution would look like this:

```java
List<User> users =
ctx.select(
     USERS.ID,
     USERS.NAME,
     multiset(
       select(KEYS.NAME, KEYS.ID)
       .from(KEYS)
       .join(USER_KEYS).on(KEYS.ID.eq(USER_KEYS.KEY_ID))
       .where(USER_KEYS.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))
     ).as("keys").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Key::new))),
     multiset(
       select(ROLES.NAME, ROLES.ID)
       .from(ROLES)
       .join(USER_ROLES).on(ROLES.ID.eq(USER_ROLES.ROLE_ID))
       .where(USER_ROLES.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))
     ).as("roles").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Role::new)))
   )
   .from(USERS)
   .where(USERS.NAME.eq("something"))
   .fetch(Records.mapping(User::new));
```

The above approach using the various [`Records.mapping()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Records.html#mapping(org.jooq.Function1)) overloads along with [ad-hoc data type conversion](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Records.html#mapping(org.jooq.Function1)) assumes the presence of an immutable constructor, such as you'd get if your classes were Java 16 records:

```java
record Key (int id, String name) {}
record Role (int id, String name) {}
record User (int id, String name, List<Key> keys, List<Role> roles) {}
```

#### Using multiple queries

If you cannot use the above approach, because you can't work with jOOQ 3.14 (yet), or because your RDBMS doesn't support SQL/XML or SQL/JSON, you can run several queries and assemble the results manually on your end.