# jOOQ fetchInto can't convert java.util.LinkedHashMap to class

Tags: kotlin, jackson, jooq

As described in this [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64931639/6409815), I want to use jOOQ (3.14.4) to map a result set into a nested collection using `fetchInto`.

I have the following SQL tables: `USER`, `USER_TO_ROLE` and `ROLE` (similar to the context assumed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38239895/6409815)).
In addition, I make use of PostgreSQL 13.1 with the following Jackson dependencies (with `jacksonVersion="2.11.3"`:

```kotlin
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$jacksonVersion")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion")
```

According to the [docs](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/#N8C599), the following Kotlin snippet should map the users and its roles to the given Kotlin class:

```kotlin
val select = mutableListOf<SelectField<out Any?>>(USER.ID, USER.USERNAME)
select.add(
    field(
        select(
            jsonArrayAgg(
                jsonObject(
                    jsonEntry("id", ROLE.ID),
                    jsonEntry("name", ROLE.NAME),
                )
            )
        )
            .from(ROLE)
            .join(USER_TO_ROLE).on(ROLE.ID.eq(USER_TO_ROLE.ROLE_ID))
            .where(USER_TO_ROLE.user().ID.eq(USER.ID))
    ).`as`("roles")
)

return dsl.select(select)
    .from(USER)
    .where(USER.ID.eq(id))
    .fetchInto(User::class.java)
```

Where `User` and `Role` are defined as:

```kotlin
data class User(
    var id: UUID? = null,
    var username: String? = null,
    var roles: List<Role>? = null,
)

data class Role(
    var id: UUID? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
)
```

Unfortunately, this yields the following exception (when a User is associated with a Role):

> Cannot convert from {id=<UUID>, name=<String>} (class java.util.LinkedHashMap) to class com.example.demo.Role

I assumed that adding Jackson would solve the question asked in the previously mentioned related question, but it doesn't.

Am I missing something?

A minimal sample project can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/sandsoft/stack-overflow/jooq/jooq-json-map)

Comment: Related issue (regarding using kotlin/jackson/jOOQ/json: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11165). Your query is not projecting anything from the `USER` table. Is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding your question: that was not intentional, and I've updated the code accordingly. I read the linked issue, but I'm not sure how I can configure jOOQ to make use of the converter. Adding the mentioned converter to my project yields the same error. Is there additional configuration involved to make that work?